# Zoom axis works but stem lines and circle not work

Tags: d3.js

I try below example to zoom stem plot.axis can be zoomed,the stem lines and circle not zoomed.

```js
var width = 900
var height = 480

var margin = {top:50,left:80,right:50,bottom:50}

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('height',height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr('width',width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .style('border','2px solid red')

//    .on('zoom', (event) => {
//      g.attr('transform', event.transform);
//    })


var g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform',`translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)

load_csvtext();
//======== done ========//

function load_from_disk() {
    Promise.all([
    d3.csv('save.csv')
    ]).then(([data]) => {
    process(data)
    })
}

function load_csvtext() {
    var csvtext = `ts,latitude,longitude
2022-04-06 07:22:01.972,26.145957,-80.254937
2022-04-06 07:22:04.972,26.145958,-80.254936
2022-04-06 07:22:07.973,26.145957,-80.254936
2022-04-06 07:22:10.975,26.145957,-80.254936
2022-04-06 07:22:13.973,26.145956,-80.254935
2022-04-06 07:22:16.977,26.145956,-80.254934
2022-04-06 07:22:19.974,26.145955,-80.254934
2022-04-06 07:22:22.974,26.145955,-80.254935
2022-04-06 07:22:25.969,26.145954,-80.254935
2022-04-06 07:22:28.974,26.145954,-80.254935
2022-04-06 07:22:31.972,26.145954,-80.254936
2022-04-06 07:22:34.978,26.145954,-80.254937
2022-04-06 07:22:37.978,26.145953,-80.254937
2022-04-06 07:22:40.981,26.145953,-80.254937,
2022-04-06 07:22:43.991,26.145953,-80.254938
2022-04-06 07:22:46.973,26.145953,-80.254938
2022-04-06 07:22:49.974,26.145953,-80.254939`
    var data = d3.csvParse(csvtext)
    process(data)
}

function process(data) {
    const tParser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    var prevts = 0
    var x = 'x'
    var y = 'y'
    data.map(d => {
    d[x] = tParser(d['ts'])
    if (prevts == 0) {
        prevts = d[x]
        d[y] = 0
    }else{
        d[y] = d[x] - prevts
        //prevts = d[x]
    }
    })
    
    var xmax = d3.max(data,d => d.x)
    var xmin = d3.min(data,d => d.x)
    var ymin = d3.min(data,d => d.y)
    var ymax = d3.max(data,d => d.y)

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([xmin, xmax])
      .range([0, width])
    var yScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([ymin, ymax])
      .range([height,0])

    var xaxis = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom()
          .scale(xScale)
          .ticks(20)
         );
    xaxis.selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-30)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

    var yaxis = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft()
          .scale(yScale)
          .ticks(10)
         );
    
    var circles = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("fill", "green")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.x); } )
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y); } )
    .attr("r", 5)

    var lines = g.selectAll(".stem")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr('class','stem')
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("x1", function(d) {return xScale(d.x); } )
    .attr("x2", function(d) {return xScale(d.x); } )
    .attr("y1", function(d) {return yScale(ymin); } )
    .attr("y2", function(d) {return yScale(d.y); } )

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([0.005, 2000])
      .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .on('zoom', zoomed);

    g.call(zoom)
    function zoomed(event) {
    var newX = event.transform.rescaleX(xScale); 
    var newY = event.transform.rescaleY(yScale)
    xaxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX));
    xaxis.selectAll("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-30)")
        .style("text-anchor", "end");
    yaxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY));

    lines
        .selectAll('line')
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return newX(d.x); } )
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return newX(d.x); } )
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return newY(ymin); } )
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return newY(d.y); } )
        //.attr("stroke", "red")

    circles.selectAll('circle')
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
        return newX(d.x);
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
        return newY(d.y);
        })
    }    
    return
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@7.0.4/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lines` and `circles` are already selections containing lines and circles, no need to select lines and circles inside them (which don't exist by the way). Just do:

```
lines.attr("x1", etc...
```

Here's your snippet with that change.

```js
var width = 900
var height = 480

var margin = {
  top: 50,
  left: 80,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 50
}

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .style('border', '2px solid red')

//    .on('zoom', (event) => {
//      g.attr('transform', event.transform);
//    })


var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)

load_csvtext();
//======== done ========//

function load_from_disk() {
  Promise.all([
    d3.csv('save.csv')
  ]).then(([data]) => {
    process(data)
  })
}

function load_csvtext() {
  var csvtext = `ts,latitude,longitude
2022-04-06 07:22:01.972,26.145957,-80.254937
2022-04-06 07:22:04.972,26.145958,-80.254936
2022-04-06 07:22:07.973,26.145957,-80.254936
2022-04-06 07:22:10.975,26.145957,-80.254936
2022-04-06 07:22:13.973,26.145956,-80.254935
2022-04-06 07:22:16.977,26.145956,-80.254934
2022-04-06 07:22:19.974,26.145955,-80.254934
2022-04-06 07:22:22.974,26.145955,-80.254935
2022-04-06 07:22:25.969,26.145954,-80.254935
2022-04-06 07:22:28.974,26.145954,-80.254935
2022-04-06 07:22:31.972,26.145954,-80.254936
2022-04-06 07:22:34.978,26.145954,-80.254937
2022-04-06 07:22:37.978,26.145953,-80.254937
2022-04-06 07:22:40.981,26.145953,-80.254937,
2022-04-06 07:22:43.991,26.145953,-80.254938
2022-04-06 07:22:46.973,26.145953,-80.254938
2022-04-06 07:22:49.974,26.145953,-80.254939`
  var data = d3.csvParse(csvtext)
  process(data)
}

function process(data) {
  const tParser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
  var prevts = 0
  var x = 'x'
  var y = 'y'
  data.map(d => {
    d[x] = tParser(d['ts'])
    if (prevts == 0) {
      prevts = d[x]
      d[y] = 0
    } else {
      d[y] = d[x] - prevts
      //prevts = d[x]
    }
  })

  var xmax = d3.max(data, d => d.x)
  var xmin = d3.min(data, d => d.x)
  var ymin = d3.min(data, d => d.y)
  var ymax = d3.max(data, d => d.y)

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([xmin, xmax])
    .range([0, width])
  var yScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([ymin, ymax])
    .range([height, 0])

  var xaxis = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom()
      .scale(xScale)
      .ticks(20)
    );
  xaxis.selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-30)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

  var yaxis = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(yScale)
      .ticks(10)
    );

  var circles = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("fill", "green")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.x);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.y);
    })
    .attr("r", 5)

  var lines = g.selectAll(".stem")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr('class', 'stem')
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.x);
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.x);
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return yScale(ymin);
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.y);
    })

  var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.005, 2000])
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .on('zoom', zoomed);

  g.call(zoom)

  function zoomed(event) {
    var newX = event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
    var newY = event.transform.rescaleY(yScale)
    xaxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX));
    xaxis.selectAll("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-30)")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");
    yaxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY));

    lines.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return newX(d.x);
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return newX(d.x);
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return newY(ymin);
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return newY(d.y);
      })
    //.attr("stroke", "red")

    circles.attr('cx', function(d) {
        return newX(d.x);
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return newY(d.y);
      })
  }
  return
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@7.0.4/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

You will see that there are several other issues, but those should be addressed in new questions (in order to keep just 1 issue per question).